# Materialize Carousel in iFrame not refreshing/redrawing when resizing the parent window

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, materialize

I'm using a [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/) Carousel within an iFrame (cross domain).

The iFrame is a fixed width unless it is resized to lower than mobile width, after which it takes the width of 100%.

If the page, and iFrame is loaded initially on a small width screen (such as an iPhone 5) - and then resized to be a desktop screen for example - the carousel is `bugged out man`.

The slides are all on top of each other and it doesn't redraw itself - or recalculate the offsets for the slides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the issue I did the following.

## Parent Page JavaScript

```
var iFrame = document.createElement('iframe');
// code excluded - setting up iFrame, setting src etc...

window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    iFrame.contentWindow.postMessage({ message: 'parent-resized' }, iFrameDomain);
}, true);
```

---

## iFrame JavaScript

```
if(window.addEventListener){
    window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage, false);        
} else if (window.attachEvent){
    window.attachEvent('onmessage', receiveMessage, false);
}

function receiveMessage(event){
   if(event.data.message === 'parent-resized'){
       $('.carousel').carousel().trigger('resize');
    }
}
```

And that's it. The carousel will do it's thing and fix the transform values.